# Concatenate Gridview Data

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a gridview with following Data

```
CustomerName  item      qty
tom           sugar      1 kg
Peter         Rice       2 Kg
Jhone         Sugar      .5 kg
tom           Rice       5 Kg
Peter         Tea        .5 Kg
tom           Tea         1 kg
```

now I want to display data with the following format:

```
tom   sugar 1kg, Rice 5 kg, Tea 1 kg
Peter Rice  1kg, Tea  .5 kg
Jhone Sugar .5kg
```

how to achieve this

Comment: What format is the 2nd example? a string?

Comment: display result to another gridview

Comment: The problem with that is that it wouldn't really be fully normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am giving logic of loop, 
i have simply typed in notepad so ignore the syntax , this is some thing like pseudo code

loop can be like this

```
for(i=0i<gv.rows.cout,i++)
{
 string name = gv.rows[i].cells[0].text.trim()
  if(ischecked(name) == false)
    {
          for(j=i;j< gv.rows.cout,j++)
          {
             string value = gv.rows[j].cells[1] + " " + gv.rows[j].cells[2];
            // you can now store this value in other datatable
and then finally bind this table with gridview after finsihing this loop

          }
    }

}

string []str = new string(20) 
public bool ischecked(string name)
{
 if found in str 
then return true
else
store in str
```

return false

```
}
```

Comment: hi parvez this code is not working  public bool ischecked(string name)
{
 if found in str 
then return true
else
store in str
return false

}

Comment: @zahidmahmood write the logic,its only pseudo code like if for (i=0;i<str.lengh;i++) { if (str[i] == name) return true; else str[k] = name; k++  return false, }  define k outside 0

Comment: you also need to define a new datatable with some column to store the merge value

Answer (score 0):

If you saying to display in particular format of grid view data then there is no other way than running loop of customer name and finding its occurrence and merging it,
rather than you should try to join the data source ,
so i suggest to show schema of data source 
so that any one can help

Comment: how to  running loop of customer name and finding its occurrence and merging it

Comment: brother i have given loop in next answer , that is simple logic , you can implement in real code :)

Comment: This logic will sure work, if any problem do post the code here,